# iphone bookmarklet cookie persistence

Tags: persistence, iphone, mobile-safari, session-cookies

I have an iphone (jqtouch based) web app that uses cookies for authentication.  The use flow is as follows :

- user goes to the mobile landing page and is instructed to save the page as a bookmarklet on their home page.
- they launch the bookmarklet to go to a login page to login and get a cookie.
- the cookie works and they can navigate throughout the web site.
- However this session cookie is not persistent.  If they leave safari and then restart using the saved bookmarklet, the cookies set during their previous session are gone.
- Just using safari (ie: launch safari directly rather than through the bookmarklet) to navigate the pages works fine (ie: start safari, go to url, do login, restart safari, go back to url).
- I find that that the cookies that were active when the bookmarklet was created are persistent but any cookies set during the session when safari is accessed through the bookmarklet are not persistent.
- I'm wondering if this is a safari/iphone issue and/or if there is any way around this.  Many thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: I am having the same issue. This actually happens because the way iphone launches the bookmarked app. using file://index.html so the domain is not same as the domain of the cookie and therefore browser does not send it with ajax requests. Larry what did u end up doing? did u use the localStorage on client side or were u able to figure out how to set the cookie when opening the web app from homescreen.

Comment: i used something like a ?v=1 at the end of some stuff to make sure it wasn't cashed once when taking a web app tutorial... <link type="text/css" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/images/template/icon.png?v=1" />  don't know if that has anything to do with cookies... but thought i would throw it out there... makes it so that mobil safari doesn't cache that specific thing...

Answer (score 2):

K, for anyone encountering the same problem, i found a work around by making use of html5's localstorage.  I just needed to use javascript to set the storage based on cookie values as the cookies were being set and to set the cookies from the storage values when the first page was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that in one of my applications. I have tried this in this way:

1. The user logs in and his cookie is set into the sharedHttpCookieStorage.
2. Check the cookie against your URL, get its values and save it in your application's storage.
3. Next time user wants to use your application, check if there is any cookie values in your storage. If Yes then create a cookie with those values else get him to log in again.
4. Make sure to clear the cookie values when the user logs out or the cookie expiration date reaches.

I know it sounds difficult but infact is really easy. All you have to go through is Apple's documentation on NSHTTPCookie.